# Adding a VLAN-transparent bridge to Linux (Debian)

Tags: debian, networking, bridge, vlan, ifupdown

On my current Debian system I use VLAN tagging and I create bridges br-wan and br-lan that I use for LXC containers:

```
auto lo br-lan br-wan

iface lo inet loopback

iface br-wan inet manual
    bridge_ports eth0.3
    bridge_maxwait 0

iface br-lan inet static
    address 192.168.200.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.200.1
    bridge_ports eth0.2
    bridge_maxwait 0
      
iface eth0.1 inet static
    address 10.7.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now I would like to add a KVM guest that gets transparent access to eth0 and in turn uses VLAN tagging internally (for example, to create a virtualized router routing between eth0.2 and eth0.3). To test, I did the following:

```
brctl addbr br-master
brctl addif eth0
```

And then I created a KVM guest with `--network=bridge=br-master,model=virtio` which creates an interface vnet0 that is also added as bridge port to br-master. Inside the guest added the VLAN interfaces.
 
On the host, I see tagged packets in vnet0 (`tcpdump -i vnet0 -e vlan`) and br-master (`tcpdump -i br-master -e vlan`).
 
However, the traffic never reaches eth0 on the host.

I am sure the story is not that simple.
How can I add such a VLAN-transparent "master bridge" to my system, without disrupting my old config?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but it should work with the `bridge vlan ...` command.

For each VLAN ID you use on `vnet0` you have to do this:

```
for vlanid in 1 2 3 4; do
    bridge vlan add dev eth0 vid $vlanid untagged
done
```